# Rendering graphical elements through command line interface in Java

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to render graphical objects in console using standard jdk API?

For instance I want to render moving image in console (not via awt/swing).

Comment: "*I want to render moving image in console (not via awt/swing).*" Then why tag with Swing?

Comment: @user1803551 because swing users are those who work with graphics more than the rest of java community

Comment: @AndrewThompson post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Comment upgraded to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console itself can only render characters..

But if you mean you want to render an image from a command line app. (that is later displayed in other apps.) then yes, though the 'moving' part does not make much sense unless you mean an animated GIF.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The console renders characters so ASCII-art is your best choice.
Also this has been answered before: [displaying-images-in-a-console-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611837/displaying-images-in-a-console-application)

Comment: The answer you referring guide to use swing/awt but I already mentioned that this is not an option for me.

Comment: No they refer to that your only option is to use AWT/SWING thus it answers that no, you can not show images in console.